# Looking for neuroinformatics related public datasets

Tags: data-request

I need to work on a research project in big data analysis. I am very interested in neuromarketing, user experience and neuroinformatics. I've searched for an interesting public dataset for my work but still haven't found one. I found one dataset: [LSW dataset](http://datahub.io/dataset/lsw-neuromarketing), but this doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. Please help me to find some suggestions or links to download free and open source public data sets on neuromarketing and advertisements.
by using neuromarketing data i plan to find out some psychological behavior patterns between Online marketing and Web UI designings. so I'm looking for "online ads and number of click it had" or "website index pages with number of visitors". and better to have region vice localized data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Miller. You should define first your problem and then ask for the data. You say that LSW is not what you are looking for... What are you looking for?

Comment: hi  Sergio Rodriguez, thanks for the awareness. i just update my  post with my requirement. thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to the Open Data SE site. Attn moderators: please migrate it there for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of neuromarketing before, sounds very niche - and unfortunately I would imagine research is being done by private companies who absolutely will not want to release their data (it might make them a bazillion gaziliion bucks).

If you're able to change the area you're looking at, try [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions). It's a regular data science competition with freely downloadable giant data sets. Look at the list of competitions (remember to check the box for 'completed' so you see all the historic ones) - I found these which might be useful:

- [Predict seizures in intracranial EEG recordings](https://www.kaggle.com/c/seizure-prediction)
- [Detect seizures in intracranial EEG recordings](https://www.kaggle.com/c/seizure-detection)
- [Reconstruct the wiring between neurons from fluorescence imaging of neural activity](https://www.kaggle.com/c/connectomics)